# Find $f(t)$ given $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I know
$$\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}=\frac{7s^3-41s^2+84s}{(s-2)(s^2-4s+13)}$$
and I have to find $f(t)$, given $f(0)=4$.

Since
$$\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}=s\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}-f(0)$$
then
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{7s^3-41s^2+84s}{(s-2)(s^2-4s+13)}-\frac{4}{s}\right\}$$
i.e.,
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{7s^2-41s+84}{(s-2)(s^2-4s+13)}-\frac{4}{s}\right\}$$

By partial fractions, I got
$$\frac{7s^2-41s+84}{(s-2)(s^2-4s+13)}=\frac{10}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{s-2}+\frac{11}{3}\cdot\frac{s-2}{(s-2)^2+3^2}-\frac{13}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{(s-2)^2+3^2}$$
Therefore,
$$f(t)=\frac{10}{3}e^{2t}+\frac{11}{3}e^{2t}\cos(3t)-\frac{13}{3}e^{2t}\sin(3t)+4$$
because
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{4}{s}\right\}=4$$

But,it's clear $f(0)\neq4$ and also, when I found $f'(t)$ using the expression above, I didn't get the same answer to $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $f'$ is not regular. Looking at the original Laplace transform, is $f'(t) = 7\delta(t)+g(t)$ with $g$ a regular function. You can see this by inspecting the degree of the rational function which is $1$ for $f'$. Thus, even if you start at $f(0)=4$, due to the Dirac delta, $f(0^+)=4+7=11$, which is consistent with your final result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, the way I did is wrong? If so, how could I fix it?

Comment: It's not that your method is wrong, it's your interpretation that is misleading. Due to the Dirac delta, $f$ presents a discontinuity at $0$. $f(0)$ is therefore ambiguous. What you are prescribing is the left limit and what you then tried to calculate with your final formula is the right limit, which do not match as expected.

Comment: I see. Because I tried other ways, and wasn't sure this is the right one.

Comment: For example, if you were to shift just the delta by multiplying by $e^{s\epsilon}$. The discontinuity is shifted to $\epsilon$ so, at zero, the function is regular. Your naive argument would work. Try to let $\epsilon\to0$ and see what happens.

Comment: Just to confirm then: the way I did is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, your final formula for $f$ is correct